# Swapping one node with the head node in single linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have to swap the node with the entered value with the head node. It must swap the links, not the data. I wrote a code but it does not work. It makes the entered node head and then It deletes the other nodes.

For example, if the linked list is: 0 1 2 3 4 5 and I enter 3, the result is 3 4 5. However, it must be 3 1 2 0 4 5.

Could you please help me find my mistake? Thanks a lot.

Here is my function in the cpp file:

```
void IntSLList::swap_nodes(int val)
{
    if (head == 0)
    {
        cout << "\nThe linked list is empty.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        int control = 0;

        for (IntSLLNode *tmp = head; tmp != 0; tmp = tmp->next)
        {
            if (tmp->info == val)
            {
                control = 1;
            }
        }

        if (control == 0)
        {
            "\nThe entered value is not in the linked list.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            if ((head == tail) || (head->info == val))
            {
                cout << "\nThe linked list will be printed exactly the same\n";
            }
            else
            {
                IntSLLNode *prev = NULL, *cur = NULL, *head_copy = NULL, *first = NULL;

                for (IntSLLNode *tmp = head; tmp->next != 0; tmp = tmp->next)
                {
                    if (tmp->next->info == val)
                    {
                        cur = tmp->next;
                        prev = tmp;
                    }
                }

                head_copy = head;
                first = head->next;
                head = cur;
                head->next = cur->next;
                cur = head_copy;
                cur->next = first;
                prev->next = head;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef INT_LINKED_LIST
#define INT_LINKED_LIST

class IntSLLNode {
public:
    IntSLLNode() {
        next = 0;
    }
    IntSLLNode(int el, IntSLLNode *ptr = 0) {
        info = el; next = ptr;
    }
    int info;
    IntSLLNode *next;
};

class IntSLList {
public:
    IntSLList() {
        head = tail = 0;
    }
    ~IntSLList();
    int isEmpty() {
        return head == 0;
    }
    void addToHead(int);
    void addToTail(int);
    int  deleteFromHead(); // delete the head and return its info;
    int  deleteFromTail(); // delete the tail and return its info;
    void deleteNode(int);
    bool isInList(int) const;
    void printAll() const;
    void  sort_list();
    void swap_nodes(int);
    int find_min();
private:
    IntSLLNode *head, *tail;
};

#endif
```

Here is the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "intSLList.h"

    int main() {
    
        IntSLList list, list2;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            list.addToHead(i);
        }
            
        list.printAll();
        list.sort_list();
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            list2.addToTail(i);
        }
        
        
    
        list2.swap_nodes(3);
        list2.printAll();
        
    }
```

Comment: Pleae read about [mcve]. You just need to swap the values, right?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I need to swap links.

Comment: why do you need to swap links? When you want to turn 0 1 2 3 4 5 into 3 1 2 4 5 then only 3 must be swapped with 0

Comment: I thought it too, it is easier like this but it is an assignment.

Comment: Please post the complete code.

Comment: what does the assignment say exactly?

Comment: Work it out using pen(cil) and paper first. Draw boxes and arrows and see what you need to do.

Comment: @molndnilo I tried like that. But I do not understand why it deletes the list.

Comment: Since you first did `head = cur;`, `head->next = cur->next;` is the same as `head->next = head->next;` and `cur->next = cur->next;`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I tried to copy cur first, it did not work either.

Comment: No, because `head` and `cur` were still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ASCII rendition of the procedure.
Translating to code left as an exercise.

```
head->0->1->2->3->4->5


----------


             here
               |
               v
head->0->1->2->3->4->5


----------


         prev  here
            |  |
            v  v
head->0->1->2->3->4->5
         ^  
         | 
       tail


----------


              here
      +-----+  |
      v     |  v
head->0  1->2  3->4->5
         ^        
         |       
        tail      
                  

----------


              here
      +-----+  |
      v     |  v
head->0  1->2  3->4->5
      |  ^        ^
      |  |        |
      | tail      |
      |           |
      +-----------+


----------


              here
      +-----+  |
      v     |  v
head->0  1->2  3  4->5
      |  ^     |  ^
      |  |---- +  |
      | tail      |
      |           |
      +-----------+


----------


 +------------------+
 |                  |
 |            here  |
 |    +-----+  |----+
 |    v     |  v
head  0  1->2  3  4->5
      |  ^     |  ^
      |  +---- +  |
      |           |
      |           |
      +-----------+


----------


 +------------------+
 |                  |
 |             +----+
 |    +-----+  |
 |    v     |  v
head  0  1->2  3  4->5
      |  ^     |  ^
      |  +---- +  |
      |           |
      |           |
      +-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It was difficult to understand your code - so I tried to make the logic simple. Hope I haven't missed anything.

Few points to note:

- Don't use 0 for null pointer, instead use `nullptr`
- Don't use integer for boolean flags, use `bool`

```
void IntSLList::swap_nodes(int val)
{
    if (head == nullptr) {
        cout << "Empty list\n";
        return;
    }
    
    if (head == tail || head->info == val) {
        cout << "\nThe linked list will be printed exactly the same\n";
    }
    
    IntSLLNode* beg = head;
    IntSLLNode* begNext = head->next;
    IntSLLNode* swap = nullptr;  // node to be swapped
    IntSLLNode* swapNext = nullptr; // node's original next ptr
    IntSLLNode* swapPrev = nullptr; // node's original prev ptr
    
    for (IntSLLNode* p = head, *prev = p; p != nullptr; prev = p, p = p->next)
    {
        if (p->info == val) {
            swap = p;
            swapNext = p->next;
            swapPrev = prev;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (swap == nullptr) {
        cout << "Not found in list\n";
        return;
    }
    
    swapPrev->next = beg;
    beg->next = swapNext;
    swap->next = begNext;
    head = swap;
    
    if (tail->next != nullptr) {
        // val == tail->info
        for (IntSLLNode* p = head; p != nullptr; p = p->next)
        {
            if (p->next == nullptr) {
                tail = p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```